# pass variable from javascript to python, without reloading page

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, ajax

I'm using cherrypy as a webserver and JS to loop over python objects(concatenating them as string to JS code) and fill optionS,radioS etc.
on the webpage user picks  from ,
I'm stuck on passing option_value to python(???)

I've read similar posts and as suggested I use ajax snippet but it reloads whole page and data being lost. UPDATE: with change in AJAX alert pops with option_value, but main question is the same- how to pass it to python(backend) from JS(frontend) ??

```
import cherrypy
class HelloWorld(object):
    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(args)
        print(kwargs)
        html = '''
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <select name='test'>
        <option value="change">Change it</option>
        <option value="verify">Verify it</option>
    </select>
</form>
<br>
<p>change above form and after submit below form verify that above still the same</p>
        <form method="POST" id="form1">
            <select name="cars" id="u_choice">
                <option value="volvo">VOLVO</option>
                <option value="audi">AUDI</option>
            </select>
          <input type="submit">
        </form>
<script>
$('form#form1').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert(e.target[0].value));
    return false;
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>'''
        return html

cherrypy.quickstart(HelloWorld())
```

Comment: Something wrong in your ajax implementation. Show us your attempt. Is it also using a form?

Comment: thank you @charlietfl for quick reply, I've added code, please let me know what needs to be fixed to stop reloading page

Comment: `preventDefault()` is not a global function and will throw error. Look in browser dev tools console. Also not sending any data with the ajax `post`

Comment: @charlietfl, please see updated script.
I'm still can't understand how to pass option_value to python from JS

Comment: Suggest you study some tutorials on using ajax and forms. A form element has no `value` itself